# Как в c# проверить цифровые подписи файла?

Tags: c#, процесс, exe, цифровая-подпись, pe

Есть программа processhacker в ней есть такой раздел. В этом разделе выводит инфу о процессе есть сертификат или нету его. Доступ к этому разделу выдает независимо от прав (админ/ не админ). Как бы так на c# эту строчку с инфой о сертификате тоже получить???[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У процессов нет подписей и сертификатов, они есть у файлов

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов ок буду знать. Как насчет проверки подписи у файла?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для файла проще всего, наверное, подключить nuget-пакет System.Management.Automation, и воспользоваться PowerShell-командой:

```
using System.Management.Automation;
```

```
static bool VerifyAuthenticodeSignature(string path)
{
    string fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(path);

    if (!File.Exists(fullPath))
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Cannot find target file", fullPath);

    using (var ps = PowerShell.Create())
    {
        ps.AddCommand("Get-AuthenticodeSignature", true);
        ps.AddParameter("LiteralPath", fullPath);
        var results = ps.Invoke();

        var signature = (Signature)results.Single().BaseObject;
        return (signature.Status == SignatureStatus.Valid);
    }
}
```

(код одолжен [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46669300/276994) и переработан).

Для получения организации, подписавшей файл, можно подсмотреть в свойства сертификата.

```
var issuer = signature.SignerCertificate.IssuerName;
var properties = issuer.Format(multiLine: true)
                       .Split(new[] {"\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                       .Select(line => line.Split(new[] {'=' }, 2))
                       .ToDictionary(parts => parts[0], parts => parts[1]);
properties.TryGetValue("O", out var organization);
```

К сожалению, я не нашёл код, который разбирает `X500DistinguishedName` в объектную структуру, но можно данный велосипед вроде бы работает. В моём примере `organization` выдало `"Microsoft Corporation"`.

Для процессов, вам нужно найти файл, из которого процесс был запущен, и проверить его точно так же.

(Впрочем, я не эксперт в вопросах безопасности, так что могу и ошибиться.)

Comment: Спасибо. Буду пробовать

Comment: @SlivinburgskayaDich: Пожалуйста! Буду рад, если поможет.

Comment: @SlivinburgskayaDich: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: этот способ подойдет только если на пк есть powershell?

Comment: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/wintrust.winverifytrust тут вроде можно без powershell (способ)

Comment: @SlivinburgskayaDich: Вот этого не знаю, объект Powershell может быть доступен и без этого. Через `WinVerifyTrust` тоже можно, но это P/Invoke, так что там всё будет куда сложнее.

Comment: `using System.Management.Automation;` ide сообщает что не существует `Automation` в  пространстве имен `System.Management`, то есть нужно дополнительно указывать ссылку на сборку? То есть, если на пк нету этой сборки то и способ не сработает?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45327912/reference-to-system-management-for-powershell-on-c-sharp-net-4-0-not-working вот с такой же проблемой столкнулся

Comment: @SlivinburgskayaDich: А вы подключили nuget-пакет? Это правильный путь.

Comment: Нет не подключил. Впервые столкнулся с "nuget-пакетами". Ну это не проблема, сделаю. Скажите пожалуйста, если на других машинах, на которых я собираюсь использовать методы, которые Вы предложили для проверки подписи не будет также по дефолту как и у меня "nuget-пакета" или `System.Management.Automation.dll`, то работать ничего не будет? Стоит тогда отдельно загрузить `System.Management.Automation.dll` и засунуть в свою сборку?

Comment: @SlivinburgskayaDich: nuget-пакет подключит dll к вашему проекту, и она будет копироваться в выходной каталог, как и другие зависимые DLL.

Comment: @SlivinburgskayaDich: Просто нажмите правой клавишей мыши на проекте, и выберите из меню _Manage NuGet packages..._

Comment: То есть, nuget-пакет — это не для компьютера, это для проекта. Nuget — это просто менеджер зависимостей, кстати.

Comment: В таком случае отлично. Буду разбираться. Спасибо Вам большое, с наступающим Вас :)

Comment: @SlivinburgskayaDich: Пожалуйста! И вас тоже!